# How to extract only the screen resolution information from xrandr output?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

```
xrandr | grep primary
```

return

```
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
```

I am interested in only the **resolution sub-string** `1920x1080` from this output.

How do I go about extracting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo 'eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm' |
awk -F'[ +]' '{print $4}'
1920x1080
```

You don't need grep when you're using awk, btw, this is all you need:

```
xrandr | awk -F'[ +]' '/primary/{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply run this,

```bsh
xrandr | grep -oP '(?<=primary )[x\d]+'
```

This outputs `1920x1080`

So, how does this works?

`(?<=pattern)pattern`<sup>1</sup> Positive Lookbehind: Check if the `text` appears before the pattern.

`[ ]` Character Set. Used to group a list of characters together.

`\d` A digit. Means the Range `0-9`

`[x\d]` Groups `\d` and `x` together. Means a list of digits and x. Which means basically this `x0123456789`

`+` Matches one or more of the previous Group.

So, `(?<=primary )[x\d]+` baiscally means match the list of characters `x0123456789` (**e.g.** 1920x1080) that appears after the text `'primary '`. Notice that there is a space character `' '` after `primary`. And only such match in your case would be `1920x1080`

You can test this regex [here](https://regexr.com/6c8fj).

**Edit:** Important Notes.

(1) With `Grep`, you can **ONLY** use fixed length lookbehinds. For example `echo '012abcde' | grep -oP '(?<=\d{3})\w+'` outputs `abcde` but `echo '012abcde' | grep -oP '(?<=\d+)\w+'` outputs the error `grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`. Thus, for *Grep* the template of **P**ositive **L**ookbehind is `(?<=fixed_length_pattern)pattern` not `(?<=pattern)pattern` or `(?<=text)pattern`.

(2) According to [@G-Man Says 'Reinstate Monica'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/80216) in the comment section below, the Option `-o` in `Grep` is **NOT** POSIX-compliant. Which means it might not many older devices. Although, from my personal experience devices that are updated in the last 4 years should work fine. Other devices might work also. Can't be more specific as I don't have that many devices to test.

(3) Again according to **[G-Man](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/80216)**, Lookbehind Assertion is supported when you pass the parameter `-P` which enables Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE). Which again might not be supported in many older devices. But again from my experience works fine in recent devices.

Comment: (1) `(?<=text)pattern` is an oversimplification; what you are doing is `(?<=pattern₁)pattern₂`.  (2) It might be worth mentioning that the `-o` option is not POSIX-compliant.  (3) You should ***definitely*** explain that (3a) `(?<=…)` is not a valid basic regular expression or extended regular expression, but is a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE), (3b) you need to specify the `-P` option to get `grep` to interpret its *pattern* parameter as a PCRE, and (3c) support for PCREs is not widespread; rather, it is present in GNU grep and few if any other places.

Comment: Edited the post. Just wanted to add that in `Grep`, **L**ook**b**ehinds only allow `fixed length patterns`. Explained in footnote `1`. So, its more likely somewhere between `(?<=text)pattern` and `(?<=pattern)pattern`. The rest are probably right.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular case you can use `cut` twice:

```
$ echo 'eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm' | cut -d ' ' -f4 | cut -d+ -f1
1920x1080
```

Notice though that parsing `xrandr` output like that is quite fragile.  On
my system for example `xrandr | grep primary` returns nothing and
resolution is in 3rd field, not in 4th.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
xrandr | sed -E -n '/primary/s/.* ([0-9]+x[0-9]+)\+.*/\1/p'
```

The `-n` option is for printing only the matching regex.

`-E` allows extended regex.

The sed command only extract the regex from the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
xrandr | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}'
```

This seemed like the simplest solution for me, I have two monitors and get the output for both.

Comment: `awk` can `grep` use `xrandr | awk '$2 ~ /\*/ { print $1}' `

Comment: Okay, ... I'll guess I'll learn how to properly use awk. Thank you for the help !